# Can Anyone explain why I'm getting 1 here?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, pointer-arithmetic, pointer-conversion

it's a pointer arithematic question

```
    //code   
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()   
    {
        int a=20,b=50,*p,*q;     
        p=&a;
        q=&b;
        int c=p-q;
        cout<<c;   //Here I'm getting 1 for all positive  value of 'a' and 'b'
        return 0;   
    }
```

**i tried long int c also**

Comment: Were you expecting something else? If so, *what* ? It would help if you stated what you were intending and expecting as part of your question. Fwiw, the values within `a` and `b` are irrelevant, and pointer arithmetic is defined for objects in-sequence, which those are not.

Comment: In C the subtraction you used is illegal. You can only do pointer arithmetic with pointers that point within the same object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are subtracting pointers, not dereferenced pointers. If you were hoping to subtract the value of `a` from `b` via your pointers, you need to be using `*p` and `*q`.

For the code as written, there is actually no guarantee for what will be output here. In other words, there is no single "correct" answer. You're taking addresses of two automatically allocated variables. The compiler is permitted to put them wherever it wants, so there is no guarantee about how far they lie apart.

Typically though, the compiler will be placing them on the stack, next to one another. So if you subtract their addresses, you'll commonly end up with either 1 or -1.

Note that the types of the pointers are `int*`, so pointer arithmetic on them will *not* be in terms of bytes (perhaps that was what you were expecting?) but units of `sizeof(int)`.

*Note also that pointer arithmetic beyond a memory "object" isn't strictly well defined according to the standard (see "undefined behaviour"), although most implementations (compilers) don't penalise you for this type of "distance" measurement directly, as it's frequently useful for implementing tree data structures and similar. (At least on modern platforms with linear address spaces.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = p - q;
```

You substracting the values of the pointers `p` and `q` itself - actually the addresses of `a` and `b` in memory and assign the result to the `int` `c`.

If you want to substract the value `20` (`a`) by `50` (`b`), you need to dereference the pointers `p` and `q` by the `*` operator to obtain the values of the objects they point to.

Use `int c = *p - *q;` instead.

---

If you want to substract the values of the pointers itself, there are to points to consider:

1. An `int` is in most cases not capable to hold the number of a memory location. Assigning an number above the range of an `int` invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). To store the number of the memory address, you need at least a `long int`.
2. The substraction is made by the pointer types itself. Thus, the result of `1`.

---

You need to define `c` as of type `long int` and cast both pointers to `long int`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int *p, *q;
    int a = 20, b = 50;

    p = &a;
    q = &b;

    long int c = (long int) p - (long int) q;

    cout << c;    
}
```

Output:

```
4 (at my execution)
```

Note that both objects `a` and `b` do not need to be stored subsequent in memory. `sizeof(int)` is not always 4, although it is common for most modern implementations.

Comment: Judging by the tags assigned by the author, i'm pretty sure the ill-conceived pointer arithmetic is actually intentional.

Comment: @WhozCraig But the comment in the provided code says "*Here I'm getting 1 for all positive value of 'a' and 'b'*". -- This implies that OP actually expect the result of the integer substraction to be in `c`. *"Pointer arithmetic"* itself might be misplaced.

Comment: I just want subtraction of addresses  i.e., address of 'a' that is stored in pointer 'p' and address of 'b' that is stored in 'q'. The  values I'm getting according to my complier p=&a=7339528=0x6ffe08 and q=&b=7339524=0x6ffe04 . According to me value for c should be 4.(7339528-7339524)

Comment: @RitikKumar I edited my answer. Note that both objects `a` and `b` do not need to be stored subsequent in memory. You can´t expect it to be 4. Also `sizeof(int)` is not always 4, although it is common for most modern implementations.